# Is it compulsory to define ngRoute on the angular module?

Tags: angularjs

I am absolutely novice to angular.js and i have some confusion, is it compulsory to define ngRoute on the angular module, as far as i think that it is require to include if we want to change the view on the basis of URl change. 
Or is it also possible to define the route and return the view manually by calling some controller and on button click and it will return a view that i can use in the my index page.

Comment: you want to define routes and corresponding templates at run time is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a app without using `ngRoute`. In that case you do not use the `nv-view` directive in html and the app does not respond to url change.

Also in that case if you want to change any part of the site, you use `ng-include` which takes parameter as the view name on server and it can be dynamically changed based on some logic.

Said that, you should use the view segregation and loading based on route as it makes your application a truly single page app, where views are update without any page refresh and each of the individual views can be bookmarked.